# Где папки lib и include у MinGW-W64 и почему их несколько?

Tags: include, lib, mingw-w64

Поясните пожалуйста, ни как не разберусь.
В папке компилятора (MinGW-W64) есть папки lib и include, также они есть и в папке x86_64-w64-mingw32 и присутствуют в папке opt.
Вопрос: почему их так много и в какие кидать библиотеки (файлы .a и .h)?
И можно ли как нибудь сделать что бы было только одно место с этими папками, как в MinGW32?

Answer (score 0):

Захламлять своим добром каталоги компилятора - моветон.
Если край, отредактировать .spec файл
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/SpecsFileHOWTO